# Reusing Certificate Signing Request for Apple Push Service

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

> The creation of a CSR will prompt
>   Keychain Access to simultaneously
>   generate a public and private key
>   pair. Your private key is stored on
>   your Mac in th....

So every iOS app can have two environments set up for push notifications, development and production.

What is the harm in reusing the same CSR (and thus the same private key?) for both dev and prod environments? Is this even possible?

In a similar effect what would be the harm of using the same CSR across the different apps.

Basically I want to manage a single private key when I install the required elements on the server that will handle push notifications on my end.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use the same private/public key for all my certificates. The only time I ever end up having different private/public keys is when a client wants me to manage their whole Apple account and certificate generation.

Comment: Good to know thanks! Although it seems Apple doesn't really want us to be doing this; from their CSR/SSL/Provisioning walkthrough: `To develop and deploy the provider side of a client/server application, you must get SSL certificates from the iPhone Provisioning Portal. Each certificate is limited to a single application, identified by its bundle ID. Each certificate is also limited to one of two development environments..`